# Was approaching this as a classification problem a mistake and should I have to use regression instead?

Tags: multiple-regression, predictive-models, model-selection, loss-functions, scoring-rules

So I am training a model to predict baseball plate appearance outcomes, which I have been modelling as a single multi-class output problem, namely because single, mutually exclusive outcomes is what plate appearances lead to in real life, and as a result that is how my labeled data is structured (i.e. only have the actual outcome of each event).

I have been running into this issue though, throughout the last month, in that the underlying "ground truth" i am seeking, for each data point, i.e. in reality, would be a probability distribution.  You can have the exact same plate appearance (at least, exact same in terms of the every single feature that i am using being equal), if say was somehow repeated IRL 100 times, would actually produce a distribution of different outcomes according to that underlying probability ground truth.  Now granted, certain events would never appear (i.e. when there is nobody on base, there wouldn't any chance of a double play happening), but several different outcomes could and certainly would appear.

This fact has caused me much consternation about choosing and interpreting loss functions and scoring rules, because I know that proper scoring rules are minimized when the "correct" label is predicted as having 100% likelyhood and all other outcomes are predicted as having 0% likelyhood (i.e. [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]. However for me, this is not ideal. What would be optimal is that the loss (or scoring rule) should be minimized when the underlying ground truth of probabilities is predicted matching the real, true ground truth (i.e. [0.11, 0.04, 0.001, 0.03, 0.09, 0.22, 0.509] for example).

Given that I don't mind TOO much if a low probability events occur in the dataset but was predicted as close to 0 probability, I thus concluded that log loss/cross entropy may be the wrong choice. But in then trying to dissect whether brier score would be any better, it is slowly dawning on me... ***should i have just been approaching this as, maybe like a multi-regression problem from the beginning?***

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! You have a complicated outcome variable, where some of the outcomes can be ordered (single, double triple) but some cannot (double play, walk, hit by pitch). I’m not sure that any of the standard approaches will be appropriate, but it would help if you said why you think this is a regression problem.

Comment: Well, i thought that because the ground truth i am looking for isn't actually a classification but a vector of probabilities.  I suppose what I meant was that i could divide it into multiple regression problems -- the underlying probability of each individual type of event outcome.

Comment: The problem with this of course is my labeled data are specific outcomes, and i don't know the actual "ground truth" probabilities. 

Side note: I do know that this has been done before (they even published a white paper on it, here https://tinyurl.com/49d3654m that sorta lays out how they did it. They actually had 21 separate outcomes types, even rare ones like catcher interference! It seems to me though, (and i have been experiencing myself trying to train my model) like cross entropy loss would blow up as a loss whenever super rare and wholly unimportant outcomes like that happen.